# Lodash pickBy in TypeScript gives error: Index signatures are incompatible

Tags: typescript, lodash, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I have the following TypeScript code:

```
interface ICamera {
  cameraId: number;
  name: string;
  state: string;
}

interface IState {
  [id: number]: ICamera;
  loading: boolean;
  error: string | null;
}

interface ICameras {
  [id: number]: ICamera;
}
```

in my code, I'm receiving an object of `IState`, and what I'm trying to do is to convert it to `ICameras` (i.e., retrieve the `number` keys in my object, and ignore the other properties)

What I was doing, and it was working fine before upgrading TypeScript and `@types/lodash` to the latest versions was this:

```
private getCamerasFromState = (state: IState): ICameras =>
  _.pickBy(state, (value, key) => _.isFinite(_.parseInt(key)));
```

But, now I'm receiving an error indicating:

- `Partial<IState>` is not assignable to `ICameras`
- `Index signatures are incompatible`
- `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ICamera'`

Can someone please explain to me what's happening here? What am I missing? Is it an expected behavior?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `pickBy` is typed to return a new object which may or may not contain the properties of the original object, which is what `Partial` does. A simpler example:

```
// obj's type is { a: number, b: number }
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2 }

// result's type is Partial<obj>, or { a?: number, b?: number }
const result = _.pickBy(obj, value => value === 1)
```

Since it's difficult (maybe impossible) to know exactly *which* keys were picked at compile time through this method, TS sort of just leaves it up to you to figure it out at runtime.

As for a solution, my suggestion is to restructure your state so you don't have to pick them out at all to begin with:

```
interface IState {
  cameras: {
    [id: number]: ICamera
  }
  loading: boolean
  error: string | null
}
```

If that's not possible for whatever reason, you could try using `omit` to get rid of the keys you *don't* want instead (TS can actually typecheck this one):

```
const getCamerasFromState = (state: IState): ICameras =>
  _.omit(state, "loading", "error")
```